# How to store the outcome of a method

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to draw squares in random positions and random rgb values and I want 1000 of them to be created. The problem I'm facing is that everytime the loop for drawing occurs, it randomizes it all again, is there any way to make this not happen

```
import pygame
import sys
import random
pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Simulation")

def safeZone():
        #Draws a top rectangle
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (50,205,50), (0, 0, 800, 100))
    
def dot():
    width = 10
    height = 10
    spawnX = random.randrange(1, 801)
    spawnY = random.randrange(1, 601)
    r = random.randrange(1, 256)
    g = random.randrange(1, 256)
    b = random.randrange(1, 256)
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (r, g, b), (spawnX, spawnY, width, height))

def population(size):
    for x in range(size):
        dot()

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    win.fill((255, 255, 255))
    safeZone() # Always draw dots after safe zone
    population(1000)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Are you eventually going to want these to move?  If so, then create a list of 100 `Dot` objects, initialize their position once, then just draw them in the `dot` function.

Comment: the variable `run` is always True so the loop will execute the population function multiple times and because of that, you are facing the problem. You should avoid calling the population method after the first time it has called

Comment: @A.Najafi  Except the `population` function is also drawing the dots.  He can't just call it once, he'll need to reorganize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dot collection, then just draw that dot collection.  Now you can update the dot positions separately, and they will redraw in the new positions.  Here, I'm having each dot move a random amount in every loop.

```
import pygame
import sys
import random
pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Simulation")

class Dot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.spawnX = random.randrange(0, 800)
        self.spawnY = random.randrange(0, 600)
        self.r = random.randrange(0, 256)
        self.g = random.randrange(0, 256)
        self.b = random.randrange(0, 256)

def safeZone():
        #Draws a top rectangle
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (50,205,50), (0, 0, 800, 100))
    
def drawdot(dot):
    width = 10
    height = 10
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (dot.r, dot.g, dot.b), (dot.spawnX, dot.spawnY, width, height))

def population(dots):
    for dot in dots:
        dot.spawnX += random.randrange(-3,4)
        dot.spawnY += random.randrange(-3,4)
        drawdot(dot)

alldots = [Dot() for _ in range(1000)]

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    win.fill((255, 255, 255))
    safeZone() # Always draw dots after safe zone
    population(alldots)
    pygame.display.update()
```

A worthwhile modification is to store the whole rectangle in the object:

```
...
class Dot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.location = [
            random.randrange(0, 800),
            random.randrange(0, 600),
            10, 10
        ]
        self.color = (
            random.randrange(0, 256),
            random.randrange(0, 256),
            random.randrange(0, 256)
        )
    def move(self, dx, dy ):
        self.location[0] += dx
        self.location[1] += dy

def drawdot(dot):
    pygame.draw.rect(win, dot.color, dot.location)

def population(dots):
    for dot in dots:
        dot.move( random.randrange(-3,4), random.randrange(-3,4) )
        drawdot(dot)
...
```

Comment: The question is about pygame. So please use [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html). You can also use [`pygame.Color`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/color.html).

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response, this worked wonderfully! I was trying to figure out how to store all of their positions separately so this was very nice

Comment: Answer with random.seed is more elegant and simple. It can just use random seed value instead of hard coded, which gives exactly desired behaviour.

Comment: I think, I understand, what question was about. Putting random.seed inside dot function will solve issue. In same time, I'm agree, that this is not optimal in general.

Answer (score 0):

You call a function `dot()` in which you have assigned randomization. You should introduce a piece of code that randomizes the values outside of the `dot()` function, and store them in a separate array, and then call the function.

Comment: A proper answer would show code demonstrating how to do this.

Comment: I think it doesn't make sense for such simple things.
But if this is rules of community -- I will take this into account

Comment: Remember that the idea here is to create a catalog of answers for posterity.  We're not just answering one person's question, we're providing a long-term service.  Thus, answers really do need to be as complete as possible.  Things like your contribution should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your description sounds like you aren't necessarily trying to store the result so much as you want the process to be the same every time, but still sort of random? You could just use a hard-coded seed?

```
import random
random.seed(10)
print(random.random())
```

See this link for more detail: [Random Seed](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_random_seed.asp)

Comment: No, you have misunderstood the problem.  He doesn't want the same random sequence each time.  He wants the positions randomized ONCE.

Comment: This is the best approach to solve original problem. It is requires only one line of code and also introduce some deterministic results. Which is standard approach in all games which uses procedure generated worlds.

Comment: @ZadaZorg It is NOT the best approach.  You have misunderstood the problem.  He doesn't want the same dots every time the game runs.  He wants a different set of positions, BUT he doesn't want them changing in every loop.  THAT is the basic problem.  The initialization needed to be out of the loop.  You are answering a question that was not asked.